# how to login with Modal popup using asp classic

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp-classic

I have login modal popup in asp classic page. its open and function fine.

but if i write direct validation code before form tag ( and close end if at end of /form) its not opening.

i have used ajax also to validate and login but when i click submit button page get disappear. But i don't want it disappear and show error and if everything is correct then it should be disappear and parent page should refresh to show if logged in.

May be many asp classic developer looking for this issue.

Below is modal popup code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="compose-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> login</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="distdiv"></div>
      <form method="get">
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="StrUserName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="user name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input name="StrPassword" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            Discard
          </button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
            Send Message
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and below code is for ajax:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getXMLHTTP() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e1) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
  }

  function getdist(StrUserName, StrPassword) {
    var strURL = "loginvalidate.asp?vtid2=" + StrUserName + "&vtid3=" + StrPassword;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {
      req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
          // only if "OK"
          if (req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('distdiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
          } else {
            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
          }
        }
      }
      req.open("GET", strURL, true);
      req.send(null);
    }
  }
</script>
```

please help me out

Comment: are you using `twitter bootstrap modal` or `jquery-ui-modal` here?

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao, i have included bootstrap and jquery. if i have remove any one of these, modal will not open. <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>, <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>